# Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'Image' object is not callable, please some one look for it?

Tags: python, image, discord.py, python-imaging-library

```py
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

...

@client.command()
async def rip(ctx, member:discord.Member=None):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.author
    
    rip = Image.open("rip.jpeg")
    
    asset = member.avatar_url_as(size=128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    pfp = Image.open(data)
    
    pfp = pfp.resize((850,850))
    
    rip.paste(pfp (489, 1169))
    
    rip.save("prip.jpg")
    
    await ctx.send(file = discord.File("prip.jpg"))
```

Error: `Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'Image' object is not callable`

Comment: Caused by a typo, should be `rip.paste(pfp, (489, 1169))` not `rip.paste(pfp (489, 1169))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this :

```
with open('my_image.png', 'rb') as f:
picture = discord.File(f)
await channel.send(file=picture)
```

It is already in discord.py so you don’t need to import anything (except discor

Answer (score -1):

Just put

`rip.close()`

at the end and you will be good to go!